# Radius of largest circle in an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

Consider an ellipse whose major and minor axis of length $10$ and $8$ unit respectively. Then the radius of the largest circle which can be inscribed in such an ellipse if the circle's center is one focus of the ellipse.

What I tried:

Assuming that major axis and minor axis of an ellipse along coordinate axis.($x$ and $y$ axis respectively)

Then equation of ellipse is $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1.$ where $a=5,b=4$

Then $\displaystyle b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$ . getting $\displaystyle e=3/5.$

coordinate of focus is $(\pm ae,0)=(\pm 3,0)$

Let equation of circle is $(x\pm 3)^2+y^2=r^2$

How do I solve it from here?

Comment: The nearer vertex is the closest point of the ellipse to the focus, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $F, F'$ the foci of the ellipse. Assume we want to find the greatest circle inscribed in the ellipse, with center $F.$

- The circle and the ellipse have a common tangent line and also a common normal in their point (points) of tangency $P,$ eventually also $P'$ if they are two.
- The normal of an ellipse bisects the angle between the lines to the foci. In our case, the normal at $P$ bisects the angle between $PF$ and $PF'.$
- The normal of a circle passes through its center.

From the above properties follows that $P,F,F'$ are collinear. Therefore, $P$ is the vertex of the ellipse lying at the major axis nearest to $F,$ and the equation of the circle is 
$$(x-3)^2+y^2=|PF|^2=4$$

Answer (score 3):

You want to minimize $r^2=(x-3)^2+y^2$ subject to $\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1$:
$$L(x,y,\lambda)=(x-3)^2+y^2+\lambda\left(1-\frac{x^2}{25}-\frac{y^2}{16}\right)\\
\begin{cases}L_x=2x-6-\frac{2x\lambda}{25}=0\\ L_y=2y-\frac{y\lambda}{8}=0\\ L_{\lambda}=1-\frac{x^2}{25}-\frac{y^2}{16}=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow (x,y)=(\pm5,0);\\
r^2(5,0)=2^2 \ \text{(min)}$$
Notes:

1) WolframAlpha [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20(x-3)%5E2%2By%5E2%20subject%20to%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7B25%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7By%5E2%7D%7B16%7D%3D1).

2) If you minimize $r^2=(x+3)^2+y^2$ s.t. $\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1$, you will get $r^2(-5,0)=2^2$.

3) Foci $(\pm c,0)$ can be found from $c^2=a^2-b^2=5^2-4^2=3^2 \Rightarrow c=\pm 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate $y$. Then find the value of $x$ where $r$  is minimised.

Answer (score -1):

Try to obtain a $r$ such that the circle intersects with the ellipse at exactly 2 points. This is when the circle is tangent to the ellipse.

Comment: There is an infinite number of circles centered at a focus that intersect the ellipse at exactly two points. That condition is insufficient for tangency. In fact, there are exactly 2 tangent circles and their intersections with the ellipse each consist of a single point.

Comment: @Trebor, if the center of the circle is in a focus of the ellipse, there are never two points of contact. This is one of properties of ellipse. If there are two common points, the circle cuts the ellipse.